# How can I manage sales reps selling special orders in BlueSnap?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, bluesnap

I'm in a business that sells subscriptions, and I employ sales representatives to promote and sell them. The rep will call or meet the potential clients and sell them the subscriptions, usually with some discount.

I'd like to be able to give the reps the ability to sell the subscriptions for the conditions they agreed with the client, either on location or via an email purchase link.

I heard about the Virtual Terminal that can do these things in the console, but I'm worried about abuse. I want to make sure the sales reps will have their name recorded for each offer they put out. Also, I don't want to give the sales reps access to the my admin Console just to use the Virtual Terminal. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right to go for the BlueSnap Virtual Terminal, it's the easiest way to create these kinds of sales on the spot. 
However, as you mentioned, the VT is inside the control panel, which could be a risk if people are sharing the admin credentials.

The best thing to do in this case is to open a user for each sales representative. Just log in as the main user to your account, go to "settings" in the right top corner, and click on "User Accounts".

For each sales representative, create an account: put in their first name, last name, email and username. This is a unique set of identifiers, so remember to select a username that will be distinct. Once you fill in all four fields and press submit, the user will be created. Then you just need to click on the blue folder to the right of the user, and in the access mark "don't allow" for everything except the Virtual Terminal.

The sales rep will get an email with their new login credentials - and they will be able to enter the Virtual Terminal once they login - and nothing else.

Also, every time they generate a link for a client - there will be a log record of their unique username along with the link they created and when it happened.